# Plotly Treemap doesn't work with go.Treemap, but does with plotly.express?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to plot a Treemap using `go.Treemap`, no errors are returned but the figure doesn't show.

The same data works fine using `px.treemap`.

Where am I going wrong?

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'Number': [3, 2, 1, 0], }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

fig1 = go.Figure(go.Treemap(labels=df['Name'], values=df['Number']))
fig1.show()

fig2 = go.Figure(px.treemap(df, path=['Name'], values='Number'))
fig2.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`go.Treemap()` requires the parameter `parents`. This parameter defines the  parent sector for each sector of the tree map.
If you don't want a hierarchy just use a list of empty strings.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'Number': [3, 2, 1, 0], }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

parents = ['']*len(df['Name'])

fig1 = go.Figure(go.Treemap(labels=df['Name'], values=df['Number'], parents=parents))
fig1.show()
```